# How to monitor window size changes using time delay in Java script?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a functionality in my javascript in which webpage content will get updated on resize of window. I want to monitor this using javascript automated window resize.

For this, I am trying something which looks like below:

```
<script>
  var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=1000,height=1000");
  setTimeout("",5000);
  myWindow.resizeTo(700,700);
  setTimeout("",5000);
  myWindow.resizeTo(500,500);
  setTimeout("",5000);
</script>
```

But it's opening a window with first configuration (width = 500 and height = 500). It's not changing it's size after time delay interval.

I am not able to figure it out what is going wrong here? Can someone help me to figure it out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript `setTimeout` is asynchronous

```
console.log("a");
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("b");
}, 5000);
console.log("c");
```

Will print:

```
a
c
b
```

It's not blocking like you could use a `wait` or a `sleep` in other languages.

So you have to do:

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=1000,height=1000");
setTimeout(function(){
    myWindow.resizeTo(700,700);
    setTimeout(function(){
        myWindow.resizeTo(500,500);
    }, 5000);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Hi...Thanks for your response. it's working :). Why can't I specify setTimeout without nesting?

Comment: Because the code that's being executed 5 seconds later is inside the callback function, so your continuation program is there. Thus, if you want to wait another 5 seconds, that's there, in the nested function.
You could also start 3 timeouts in a row at 5000, 10000 and 15000ms, to avoid nesting, but that does not apply to the general case.

To ease writing async code, Javascript has Promises, but may be beyond your skills for the moment.